# How to have custom font for matplotlib axis labels?

Tags: matplotlib

This changes the axis labels to the font i want but how do i change the NUMBERS along each axis?

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/Users/NAME/Downloads/GARA.ttf')


sns.lineplot(x=stlr_df['Number of Steps'], y= stlr_df['Learning Rate'], color='purple')


plt.xlabel('Number of Steps',fontproperties=prop, size=14)
plt.ylabel('Learning Rate',fontproperties=prop, size=14)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `fontproperties` argument of [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

```py
plt.xticks(fontproperties=prop, size=14)
plt.yticks(fontproperties=prop, size=14)
```